# how to build a long distance wired network

Tags: networking, ethernet, fiber, coaxial

My house is 500 meters far from the outer gate, on a steep hill, and there is no straight path or line of sight between the 2 points. How would be the best way to extend the internet connection from the outer gate to my house router ? I have read this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156031/very-long-distance-ethernet-connection-for-internet-and-other-data-2000-feet) that solves the problem using ethernet extenders like [this](http://www.trendnet.com/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=265_TPA-311) and another [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/328307/long-distance-networking-options) that recommends using optic fiber and media converters like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009B5AA). I only need the network for common home usage and the coaxial cable from the ISP is standard RG-6

If I choose the first option (extenders) how exactly would the setup look like ? My guess: the coaxial cable from my ISP would go into the modem and the modem would connect to the first extender placed near the outer gate with RJ45 cable. Then a 500 meters coaxial cable would link this extender to a second one, and a RJ45 cable would link the second extender to my router. Is there a way the modem can be placed at the end point (my house), and the ISP cable would go directly into the extender ?

If I choose the second option (media converter) I guess I would have to do something similar: to keep the modem next to a media converter, by the outer gate, connected via RJ45 cable and then link the first converter with a 500 meters cable to a second converter to change back from light to electricity ? In this case would the 2 converters be different ?

Which approach is the easiest/best one ? Where can I find more detailed instructions ? Which compatibility issues should I care about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coaxial is an improvisation. Even if you manage to make it work at that distance you will have many possible interferences.

Take 2 identical media converters and fiber. 100MBit MCs are relatively cheap and fiber is also very cheap at the moment.

You will have a setup like: ISP-->ISPModem-->RJ45-->MC-->Fiber-->MC-->RJ45.

Alternately, at that distance, you can use Ubiquity antennas, which, if there are no big masses of metal in-between (or a big hill - your line of sight details are not clear), will certainly work.

Comment: Hi, @Overmind. There are a lot of trees in the way, do you think an Ubiquity antennas can overcome this ?

Comment: Yes. You only need to worry about metals and/or hills. Trees are fine.

Comment: about the line of sight: the house is up on a hill but trees and houses block the view

Comment: I would only need to buy one of this https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/litebeam-m5 ?

Comment: 2 UBNT nanostation 5s should do in your case very well - 1 for source and 1 for destination. It's a point to point connection.